# curl: pass a GET request as argument

Tags: windows, command-line

Heroku has this nice command which allows me to use curl to download a file which works fine in UNIX:

```
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

The command in backticks yields a very long URL that is difficult to copy/paste into my Windows CMD console.

Since backticks don't seem to work in Windows, what is the equivalent in Windows? My research on CMD went into deep dives into creating a batch file which I think is overkill for this small purpose. Googling curl's man pages yielded nothing that popped out. Googling around for other resources seem to indicate generating a POST request, which I don't think this is.

What's the equivalent command in Windows CMD? thanx, sam

Comment: Windows' CMD.EXE is not a real grown-up shell. I recommend you install cygwin and work with BASH under Windows.

Comment: See ["Batch Files - How to set commands output as a variable"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820/12892) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: According to https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/31/10334556.aspx "The Windows command processor does not have direct backquoting, but you can fake it by abusing the FOR command"... see also above comment.

Comment: In cygwin => curl -o latest.dump `heroku.bat pgbackups:url` => 
appears that curl is working but the % Received is all zeroes across the board. As opposed to Terminal in the Mac. I don't see why that would happen in cygwin.

Comment: Reading the SO post, it's not clear how this relates to my command. It appears that this is going to be a .BAT file with some arguments passed to it, because I see the %%. But it's not clear to me how a BAT file would interact with this command.

Comment: The link mpy offers has the context I needed to see how it fits. It appears the CMD does not like the &Expires ... and bails, killing the download. I just wish I can get cygwin to successfully download the file since it passes the entire URL. mpy turn yours into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: (i) I've posted my above comment as an answer. `:)` (ii) I was lucky to read your latest comment (left the page open `;)`), because if you want to notify a user via his inbox, you need to use `@username` in your comment. See this [Meta.SE Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more details. (iii) Regarding cygwin, have you tried `curl -o lastest.dump "$(heroku pgbackups:url)"`? (However it would be better, if you open up a new question on this problem...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is no original research, but borrowed from [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/31/10334556.aspx).* There it is stated that

> There is no obvious way to read the output of a command into a (...) variable. In unix-style shells, this is done via backquoting. (...) **The Windows command processor does not have direct backquoting**, but you can fake it by abusing the FOR command.

And here is an example with such a *for* command, resembling unix's `` echo `your_command` ``:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('your_command') do @echo "%i"
```

- `/f` activates the following syntax (see `help for` for more info):

  ```
  FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
  ```
- `delim=` disables the splitting at white spaces
- `@echo` prints the content of the variable `%i`, but the echo call itself is suppressed (`@`)

Answer (score 0):

As @Eugen Rieck already stated, I suggest you use a proper terminal too. But regarding your question:

- The *backticks* are used to execute something and using its result inline, they *evaluate* a command:

  ```
  echo `date`
  ```

  Or

  ```
  echo $(date)
  ```

  Will print:

  ```
  mar jul  1 11:46:42 CDT 2014
  ```

  So in your case it's trying to execute `heroku` command with `pgbackups:url` as a parameter. You can refer to this question: [Batch Files - How to set commands output as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820/12892) as *Christian* suggests on the comments.
- And to pass a parameter to a `GET` request you should simply append said params to the URL, for instace, if you want to pass a variable named `number` with the number `10` and a variable named `text` that holds `"I'm a text"`, your URL should look like this:

  ```
  "http://example.com/script.php?number=10&text=I'm+a+text"
  ```

Comment: This is excellent background, thank you. The link presented is fine but lacked additional info that the other link provided. That other link worked for me.